# Spring Boot RestController + Jackson : deserialize array of JSONObject to Map<String, String>

Tags: spring-boot, jackson, mapping

I receive from the frontend of our projet a result like this :

```
{
   someField: 'lorem ipsum',
   codesList: [
      { type: 'BARCODE', code: '1618496'},
      { type: 'LOLCODE', code: '000222'}
   ]
}
```

and in my Spring Boot REST Controller, I created a dto to be mapped when receiving the object :

```
public class ProductDto {
   private String someField;
   private Map<String, String> codesList;
   // ACCESSORS
}
```

I want to map the first value of the object as the key in my Map, and the second value as the Map value. So in the e.g, it would give me a Map like :

```
@HashMap({key: "BARCODE" , value: "1618496"}, {key: "LOLCODE", value: "000222 "})
```

My REST endpoint method is :

```
  public ResponseEntity<ProductDto> addProduct(@RequestBody ProductDto productDto) {
       // it doesn't even reach this part, because I have a parsing exception with the Map<String, String>
    }
```

With Jackson, I started to look at @JsonCreator or @JsonSubType annot but it doesn't seems to answer to my needs.

Comment: It looks like codesList in your ProductDto shouldn't be Map<String, String> but List<Code> (Or List<XXX>) and then Code should have two attributes, String key and String value

Comment: yep that's what I ended doing. But I was expected to not use logic in my mapper to convert to Map<String, String> <-> List<ProductCode>, and to just deserialize the Array of Object directly into Map<String, String> so I could keep this type for both Product and ProductDto ...